# Why can't I use part of this AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a jQuery ajax call:

```
$.ajax ({
    url : 'foo/bar/',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        var newHeaderText = $(data).find('#header-text').text();
        $("#header-text").text(newHeaderText);

        var newContent = $(data).find('#content').html();
        console.log(newContent);
        $("#content").html(newContent);
    }
});
```

The logged `data` successfully shows the complete html of the target page.

The `header-text` section works as expected.

The `console.log(newContent)`, however, returns `undefined`. Short of posting the entire html of `foo/bar/` here, suffice it to say that I am quite sure a div of id `content` is in `data`, and that it has many child elements.

Why is my attempt at grabbing the content of one page and plopping it into the content of another page not working. It is especially confusing to me as `header-text` seems to work just fine.

Comment: You're missing quite some semicolons.

Comment: js is not my native language =P. edited.

Comment: @BramVanroy Please correct me if I'm wrong (inexperienced in JS), but JS doesn't actually *need* semicolons does it?

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 technically no, but including them is much better practice. For one it shows that the programmer intended the line to finish at that point, and that nothing has been accidentally removed. It also stops errors in some minifying algorithms.

Comment: can you post the results of logging this: `$(data).find('#content');` ?

Comment: @ochi logging output of your request: `[prevObject: n.fn.init[33], context: undefined, selector: "#content"]`

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 They are not required, but you can compare it to leaving out the last semicolon in a CSS block. Generally it's bad practice, especially concerning maintainability. In JS it is even worse. The JS interpreter will "add" virtual semicolons when they are missing. But when you start leaving them out things can go downhill quickly. See the examples in [these documents](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/js20-2000-07/rationale/syntax.html).

Comment: @BramVanroy Thank you for that explanation!

Comment: Most likely it is a top level element, so you'd have to use .filter to get it since .find only looks at the descendants of the current selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [`$.parseHTML`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) instead:

```
var newContent = $($.parseHTML(data)).find('#content');
```

If `#content` is a top-level element, then the above code might still miss it. You could then solve this by first loading the HTML in container, and then find the element in there:

```
var newContent = $('<div>').append($.parseHTML(data)).find('#content');
```

Comment: It is indeed a top level element, I am just dense and forgot that. But why bother parsing html? Why not just use `$(data).filter('#content').html();`? Both mine and yours work, so why add all the complexity?

Comment: Filter works if you *know* that it is a top level element. But what if you don't know? Then finding from within a container will have success in either case. From my tests the first code also works for top elements, so it could be that simple.

Comment: Interesting way to add robustness. Thanks for the tip!